# How do I implement a tab control with vertical tabs in C#?

Tags: winforms, tabs

How do I implement a tab control with vertical tabs in C#?

Comment: Can you put this in context? (e.g., on a form with a bunch of controls, on a web page, in a text editor?)

Comment: Which platform - Windows application, WPF, ASP.NET, ASP.NET MVC... etc...

Comment: Bob; The title of the tab is usually on top. I want it to be on the left.

John; Windows Application

Comment: Ah... that's better! When I thought of "vertical tab", I was thinking of the action (i.e., VTAB) not the control.

Comment: Bob: yeah... I was all set to post "easy, just use \v"... **grin**

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Create an instance of System.Windows.Forms.TabControl (one of the standard container controls for Windows Forms) and set the Alignment property to Left.

Comment: And, if you'd prefer the text to be displayed horizontally as well, perform the steps [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404305.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

First set in properties the Alignment property to Left.

Second set SizeMode property to Fixe.

Third  set ItemSize property  to prefered size example width :30 height :120.

After that you need to set the DrawMode property to OwnerDrawFixed.
Next step is define a handler for the DrawItem event of TabControl that renders the text from left to right.

Example 
In form Designers.cs file

```
TabControl.DrawItem += new DrawItemEventHandler(tabControl_DrawItem);
```

Definition for tabControl_DrawItem method:

```
private void tabControl_DrawItem(Object sender, System.Windows.Forms.DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics g = e.Graphics;
        Brush _textBrush;

        // Get the item from the collection.
        TabPage _tabPage = TabControl.TabPages[e.Index];

        // Get the real bounds for the tab rectangle.
        Rectangle _tabBounds = TabControl.GetTabRect(e.Index);

        _textBrush = new System.Drawing.SolidBrush(Color.Black);

        // Use our own font.
        Font _tabFont = new Font("Arial", (float)12.0, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

        // Draw string. Center the text.
        StringFormat _stringFlags = new StringFormat();
        _stringFlags.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
        _stringFlags.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
        g.DrawString(_tabPage.Text, _tabFont, _textBrush, _tabBounds, new StringFormat(_stringFlags));
    }
```

Effect:[Ready horizontal tabcontrol](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1RVA.png)

I was based on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404305(v=vs.110).aspx